# Java. static {instance = new Instance();} What does it mean?

Tags: java

Java. I have found this code in my book about Spring Framework. What does it mean?:

```
static {
   instance = new Instance();
}
```

Comment: static initializer block

Comment: if you need help understanding this, you should study the very basics, not a framework like spring

Answer (score 1):

This create statically a new instance of the object. At class level